# Объект, встречающийся чаще всего в списке

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать метод, который возвращает объект, который встречается в списке чаще всего.

Например, у меня в списке хранятся разные цвета: Color.black , Color.white, Color.blue....
И я должен определить, что цвет Color.randcolor встречается чаще всего.

Но как это сделать...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то в голову пришла геморойная, но, все-таки идея:
создай мапу, ключ - цвет, значение - количество элементов в списке этого цвета
Дальше просто идешь по списку и обновляешь нужные значения. 
Дальше сортировка и ответ.

Comment: Только для поиска максимума сортировка не нужна. Достаточно одного прохода.

Comment: можно и так)
Просто не спал всю ночь, вот и предложил первое, что в череп заглянуло)

Comment: с мапом наверное самое простое решение

Answer (score 2):

"Ядро" элемента списка может быть примерно такое. В данном случае при каждом доступе к цвету сохраняется время когда был доступ. Конечно можно более хитро определить что такое "частый" доступ и сохранять скажем количество обращений за последние сутки/час и проч.

Далее в общем уже не составляет написать метод в классе MyList который выдаст "наиболее часто используемый цвет".

```
class ListElement {
   private long lastUsed;
   private Color color;

   public Color getColor() {
       lastUsed=System.getCurrentMillis();
       return color;
   }

   public long getLastUsed() {
       return lastUsed;
   }
}

class MyList {
   private ArrayList<ListElement> myList;
   //...
}
```

Comment: зачем время?)) надо group by )))

Answer (score 1):

Существует такое понятие как LRU кэш, про него можете почитать везде :), так вот если взять для примера LinkedHashMap и хранить там ваши цвета, то верхним элементом будет тот - к которому больше всего обращались, что в общим и решает вашу задачу.

upd

Без велосипедов лучше использовать коллекцию, хранить пару ключ - цвет, значение - количество использований, обернуть добавление в метод, который в случае копии ключа - инкрементирует значение, т.е способ как выше, просто есть коллекции, которые не хранят дубли ключей - из-за этого не надо лишний проверки.

Comment: LRU==Least Recently Used

Comment: С LinkedHashMap номер не пройдет, т.к. порядок элементов не изменяется при повторной встаке элемента.

Comment: @a_gura, погугли, пройдет. В этом вопросе надо количество повторов в списке, я не понимаю этого подхода, зачем складывать копии?, имхо, это больще похоже на кэш, который может подойти.

Comment: Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is re-inserted into the map.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

И вопрос все-таки про самый часто встречающийся элемент в списке.

Answer (score 1):

Решается с помощью группировок библиотеки [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/):

```
List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(new Item("1"), new Item("2"), new Item("3"));
Group<Item> group = selectMax(group(items, by(on(Item.class).getValue())).subgroups(), on(Group.class).getSize());
```

P.S. Код не запускал, но должно работать.

Answer (score 0):

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce ) ну если конечно планируете использовать распределенную сеть для подсчета ))